Using VLD to get the bytecode for php files
I'm currently working on  a project that involves analysis of the bytecode for PHP files. I'm still working on the underlying framework and concept and was hoping to find an easy way to export PHP files to .bc bytecode filetypes, such that it can be used by analysis tools (such as KLEE).
While exploring ways to do this I found vld which seemed like an excellent option.
While I am unfamiliar with bytecode overall and this is an entirely new concept to me, vld seemed like an excellent way to do this and after some messing around I was able to see the conversion in my terminal as well as read through and verify it for some rudimentary php files.
After trying for a very long time, I was able to export the vld output to a temporary folder using
php -d vld.active=1 -d vld.execute=0 -d vld.dump_paths=1 -d vld.save_paths=1 test.php 2 > error.log

However this results in a file type of .dot instead of the desired .bc.
I've tried changing the vld.dump_paths variable to my desired path, and even to a desired .bc file (hoping it would overwrite my empty one!) but have had no luck. Was hoping someone might have some help!

PHP opcodes have nothing to do with LLVM bitcode.
